# Keep keyboard open on page and disable every close option

Tags: flutter

I have an app with 2 pages. The first page is the main menu, and when you navigate to the 2nd page, a keyboard open himself inside a TextField (autofocus).

What I want to do is disabling every ways of closing the keyboard. Right now, it doesn't close when you submit, but that's the only thing I achieved to do.
The user can still close it with every other ways (in my case, it's the android navigation bar who has the left button who can dismiss it).

Is there any ways to keep the keyboard open during the whole time an user stays on a page?

EDIT:
I found this package : [keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility) to do that inside `initState`:

```
KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(onHide: () {
  setState(() {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focus);
  });
});
```

Each time I hide the keyboard, `onHide` is called and I can execute some code. Here I try to focus the TextInput again to re-open the keyboard immediately. When the keyboard is hided, the function is called, but  `requestFocus` doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());`

Comment: I don't really want to focus a TextField dynamically, I want to disable every ways of hiding the keyboard to keep it the whole time an user stays on the page.